# CSS/JS/jQuery positioning of div that animates under another div....like a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

could anyone help me with figuring out how to make a little drop down under a div with another div on a page using jquery.

this is what I have thus far (jquery/jquery UI)...

http://jsfiddle.net/hqSEJ/29/

basically the idea i trying for though this needs fixed as i guess its css needs adjusted for page sizes? so that the drop down div is always under the user tag kind of thing.

anyway i dont know if anything I am trying here is the right/best approach but i am just try to learn it so feel free to offer better ways please. thanks!

mark-up:

```
<div id='top-wrapper'>
            <div id='top-inner-wrapper'>
                <div id='title'>Main Title</div>
            <div id='user-like-item'>User Name Type Thing</div>
        </div>     
    </div>
    <div id='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div id='hidden-drop-down' style='display:none;'></div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#user-like-item").hover( function () {
           $(this).addClass("highlighted-user"); 
            $("#hidden-drop-down").show('slide', { direction: 'up'}, 1000);
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("highlighted-user");
              $("#hidden-drop-down").hide('slide', { direction: 'up'}, 1000);
        });
    });
```

styles i tried:

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0
}
        #top-wrapper{
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#2d2d2d;
            min-height:50px;
        }

        #top-inner-wrapper{
            width:70%;
            margin:0 auto;
            color:white;
            border-right:1px solid white;
            border-left:1px solid white;
        }

        #title, #user-like-item{
            width:40%;
            float:left;
            font-family:segoe ui;
            font-size:1.3em;
            font-weight:lighter;
            margin:2% 0;
        }

        #user-like-item{
            float:right;
            font-size:.8em;
            margin-top:30px
        }

        .highlighted-user{
         color:#fa3701;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        #hidden-drop-down{
            min-height:100px;
            background-color:#e0e0e0;
            border:1px solid #2d2d2d;
            position:fixed;
            left:58%;
            width:20%;
            top:55px
        }
```

EDIT: apologies for the unclear question. So I would like to have a div drop down from another div (like that user name thing). I am just learning this so there may be an numer of better ways but the fiddle is what i fiddled with. It seems that the positioning of the drop down div is not as it should be...if i resize the page it is not aligned properly. just wondering how to fix this, or better yet what else could be done as improvement? does that make sense?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Good update on the question. Let me check it

Comment: @Justin: Check my new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, one thing I can recommend immediatly is using jQuery `toggle` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user-like-item").hover( function () {
       $(this).addClass("highlighted-user"); 
       $("#hidden-drop-down").toggle('slide', { direction: 'up'}, 1000);
    });
});
```

And about the question: **HOW** do you want to position it. What do you want to achieve?

**Update**

Alright, I got it for you.

You made it very difficult to solve because your layout is built with a variety of different properties and hence the design wasn't responsive.

Let me teach you a few basic lessons which can prevent flaws in the future:

- If you float right, float everything right (for your case)
- If you float left, float everything left (for your case)
- Always give a **width** and **height** to each element
- Giving *relative* widths and heights to menu items or other items that need to be 'traced' is not a good idea
- If you want your design to be responsive, try to avoid absolute positioning. Otherwise, [read this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).
- Giving relative margins complicates things **a lot**. Rather make the width of your elements responsive instead of their respective margins.
- It is often smart to put a wrapper around your complete content such that you have absolute control over its positioning and over mouse movements

### HTML

Now let's take a look at the new **HTML** I wrote:

```
<div id='content-wrapper'>
  <div id='top-wrapper'>
      <div class='top-inner-wrapper'>
          <div id='title'>Main Title</div>
          <div id='user-like-item'>User Name Type Thing</div>
      </div>     
  </div>
</div>    

<div class='top-inner-wrapper'>
    <div id='hidden-drop-down' style='display:none;'><br>You can still hover over me</div>
</div>
```

- As you can see, I put a wrapper around the `content` and around the `top-wrapper`. I did this because we need to trace the mouse movements as you will see in the jQuery below.
- Also, I made the `top-inner-wrapper` a class such that I can apply it's (complex!!!) CSS properties to the `hidden-drop-down` as well.

### CSS

```
body {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;    
}

*{padding:0;margin:0}
#top-wrapper{
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#2d2d2d;
    min-height:50px;
}

.top-inner-wrapper{
    // just put the width at 100%. 
    // because a width of 70% is very complex to work with
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:white;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-left:1px solid white;
}

#title, #user-like-item{
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    font-family:segoe ui;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:lighter;
    // I changed from relative margin (10%) to absolute margin
    margin-left:20px;
}

#user-like-item{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin-top:30px;
    // changed to color so I can track it's width
    background-color:yellow;
    // Relative margin: I don't like it but this is what you had
    margin-right:10%;
}

.highlighted-user{
 color:#fa3701;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#hidden-drop-down{
    // Now these changes are important

    // ABSOLUTE HEIGHT
    height:100px;
    // ABSOLUTE WIDTH
    width:200px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    border:1px solid #2d2d2d;
    top:50px;
    // RELATIVE MARGIN: because you also did this at `#user-like-item`
    right:10%;
    margin-right:-1px;
    position:absolute;

    // float:right !!!
    float:right;
}

#content-wrapper {
    // always let the wrapper be 100%
    width:100%;

    // you can specify height of page here (or do auto if you actually have content)
    height:600px; 
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user-like-item").hover( function () {
       $(this).addClass("highlighted-user");

        // if hover over #user-like-item: slide down
        $("#hidden-drop-down").slideDown(function()
        {
            // only slide up if mouse has entered #content-wrapper
            $("#content-wrapper").mouseenter(function()
            {
                 $("#hidden-drop-down").slideUp();                               
            });
            // only slide up if mouse has entered #top-wrapper
            $("#top-wrapper").mouseenter(function()
            {
                 $("#hidden-drop-down").slideUp();                               
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Note that with this new jQuery, the hidden sliding div will **not** go away immediatly like you had before. This because you still would like the user to be able to read/click the div. I mean: what's the use of a sliding div if it slides right back up again.

You can find my corresponding jsFiddle [by clicking this](http://jsfiddle.net/SvSS9/).

I hope this helps you out.

Good luck.

Comment: yeah apologies for unclear question....i would like the drop down div to be fixed under the user-like div, so that when you hover on the name the drop down appears. fiddle is as far as i got but i think the css is wrong because it moves around?

Comment: thanks so much with all the help; even the next question i would have asked about hovering within the drop down.....greatly appreciated.